# JMS EXception while creating JMSFactoryFactory instance

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, mq

I am trying to create JMS connection with MQ without JNDI lookup so I was instantiating `JmsFactoryFactory` object. Below is my code, I got all the jar files added to classpath but I am getting JMSException without any clear exception message.

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;    
import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory;    
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants;   

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
      // Create a connection factory
      JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);

    }
    catch (JMSException jmsex) {
      jmsex.printStackTrace();
    }      
  }
}
```

The error message I am getting is

> javax.jms.JMSException at
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(JmsFactoryFactory.java:206)

I would appreciate if someone could please point out what is wrong here.

Comment: found the issue, one of the jar file was missing. I added couple of lines to catch block to get a meaningful error message.                                public class Test {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        
     try {
       // Create a connection factory
       JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
     
     }
     catch (JMSException jmsex) {
       System.out.println(jmsex.getErrorCode());
       System.out.println(jmsex.getLinkedException().getCause());
       System.out.println(jmsex.getMessage());
       
     }    
 }

Comment: Make sure that com.ibm.mqjms.jar is the classpath - that will refer to all the dependent JARs that might be required.

Iterating over the exception causes is a good practice and does help as shown!